# Statistical test to correlate change in one variable over time period vs. change in another change period over the same period?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I am looking at a dataset with **two variables** (x and y). Each variable is measured at the beginning of the study period (2005) and at the end of the study period (2010). Is there any hypothesis test that would allow me to measure how the **difference in x from 2010 to 2005** correlates with the **difference in y from 2010 to 2005**? In a sense, I am looking at whether, for example, an increase in x from 2005 to 2010 was also significantly associated with an increase in y from 2005 to 2010.

The way that I am currently doing this is generating 2 variables: Δx from 2005 to 2010 and Δy from 2005 to 2010, and correlating these 2 new variables by **linear regression** to determine if the beta coefficient is significant. Is there a better statistical test I can be using to find the pairwise correlation between the change in x over the course of a time period to the change in y over the course of the same time period?

Thank you!